# «Охота была» и «охота было»

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Какая фраза правильна? Обе возможны?

> Те, кому охота была посмеяться.
>
> Каждому охота было еще раз увидеть.

Comment: Поменять бы местами окончания.

Comment: Ситуация такая, как и с: *пару минут прошло*.